# Replace one Ubuntu with another from USB pen drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

I'm new to Linux. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. Now i want to install Ubuntu 12.04 .

I got an ISO  image of Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.
I put this image in to a pen drive which is formated,set the boot option boot from usb but nothing happened .

I searched this over the net and on Ubuntu website but nobody has given the complete steps . someone say you can install from the Ubuntu also ,someone says u can  do a fresh installation from usb pen drive you need to make you pen drive bootable etc. etc. .

My problem is that i don't know the exact steps how ton install Ubuntu from usb pen drive?

All I want to do is to completely remove my Ubuntu 11.04 and install Ubuntu 12.04 from usb pen-drive.

Can any body tell me how to make a pen drive bootable ?

How to install Ubuntu 12.04 from pen-drive?

Please give me a step by step procedure with screenshots.

Thanx in advance

Comment: do you want to upgrade your 11.04 or do you want too make a fresh 12.04?

Comment: How did you put the ISO image on the USB? Copy/paste?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is no easier way than this illustrated [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

In short:

- After [Downloading Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator (for the dash click the icon on top right).
  [image]
- Start the Startup Disk Creator and Click on `Other`
  [image]
- Then select `open` and search the location that you have downloaded Ubuntu (normally in ~/Downloads)
- Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk'.
  [image]

Taken from this excellent [guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score -1):

When you start up there is a moment in the lower right of the screen where it says 
F12 Boot. Hit F12 right when you see that then boot from USB.