# How do I reinstall/change to another linux destribution?

Tags: system-installation

My computer currently only has Ubuntu on it and I'd like to change a linux distrubution or reinstall linux
I know there is an option in windows to return the PC to factory settings, is there a similar option in ubuntu? can I use a boot manager to boot from a USB and then reinstall Ubuntu from there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace one Ubuntu with another from USB pen drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150082/replace-one-ubuntu-with-another-from-usb-pen-drive)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to try different flavor of Ubuntu or different distribution entirely, I suggest you install that in [VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox). This will save you trouble on installing-reinstalling, and possibly going back to Ubuntu if you chose so.

However if you insist, here is a general guide on installing different OS on your machine

1. Download `*.iso` of the desired Linux distribution
2. Use `Startup Disk Creator` or another app of your choice in Ubuntu to create a bootable USB or DVD
3. Reboot your machine and on the initial screen with your manufacturer logo, and press the key assigned to changing boot order. Most commonly the button is F12, but depending on your BIOS it may be different.
4. Select your installation media as the boot device.
5. Follow installation instructions for your desired Linux distro. This should be provided on the distro's website

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention is a bit unclear for me.From my point of view your intention is to reinstall ubuntu in a clean state. If so you can download ubuntu/any linux and pick a usb and put the ubuntu/linux (You can google about unetBootin) and install via usual way (Going to Bios->Boot Options and set usb as 1st boot device and so on). 
 If you want to get rid of unnecessary software and packages you could run the following commands
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

One of my favorite part in ubuntu or any linux is the way the os keeps the files, normally you'd never want to go for re installation due to bloatware