# Reinstall Ubuntu on dead computer

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I installed ubuntu, however I do not remember any of my login info. I would like to reinstall using a usb. I would like to install Ubuntu on a Lenovo PC with no Windows OS installed on HD. How do I install ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace one Ubuntu with another from USB pen drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150082/replace-one-ubuntu-with-another-from-usb-pen-drive)

Comment: Are you hoping to retain the documents and settings in your /home folder, or do you want to start again from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to start over, then a fresh installation would be suffice. All you have to do is to [download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (if you don't have it already). After that, you can create a [Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) on your Mac. Then, boot up the OS on the Lenovo PC and you will get to a screen like this:

[image: Reinstall image]

Of course, the version of Ubuntu will be particular to the one you downloaded. You have four options, but you want is the third option(from the top).

From there, follow the instructions, and you should have Ubuntu up and running in the next 5-10 minutes!

[Image reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317501/how-to-make-a-clean-re-install-over-a-same-release-version)

Comment: You might also choose Something Else !  Then manually select the partition where your Ubuntu was before, select to mount as ROOT - but do not format,  - when your ubuntu is reinstalled you will probably find all your old files, documents and mails!